# tkinter: user defines folder name throug entry

Tags: python, tkinter, directory, createfile

I am new to tkinter, and i have been trying to have an entry input create and name a folder in the directory. I can create a folder, but i can not get the entry variable to name the folder. I have been stuck on this for a few days now and would appreciate any example code you can make available for me. Thank you.

WOW!!! I've been trying to figure this out for 4 days now.... it just came to me... So simple. I'll share.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os,sys, shutil

master = Tk()

v = StringVar()

e = Entry(master, textvariable=v)
e.pack()

def pt():
   final_path = os.path.join('./' + str(v.get()))  
   os.mkdir(final_path) 

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=pt)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we can tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shared your solution, and this is a Q/A site, I will do my best to answer the question for further visitors :)

I think you are over-complicating the business here, since this can be done like this as well:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os,sys, shutil

master = Tk()

def b_command():
    final_path = os.path.join('./' + str(e.get()))  
    os.mkdir(final_path)

e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

b = Button(master, text="get", command=b_command)
```

This is nothing different, but setting up a "TextVariable" and using `.get()` on it is not practical because it might cause slowdowns, and in your case, prevent the code from being executed correctly.

I am curious of your solution though. Be sure to share it as soon as possible :)

Regards.

EDIT: Fixed the Button syntax.